# Elixir Ecto rollback migrations with indexes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am currently having a bunch of migrations that create a few tables with references and a few unique indexes. This seems to be working fine when I want to migrate the tables with `mix ecto.migrate` but if I want to rollback `mix ecto.rollback` coughs up the below error. Do I need to change my migrations to add something to handle the indexes during the rollback?

Migration step:

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateTokens do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:tokens) do
      add :token, :string
      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all, on_update: :update_all)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:tokens, [:user_id])
    create unique_index(:tokens, [:token], unique: true, name: :unique_tokens_index)
  end
end
```

Error Log:

```
[info] == Running App.Repo.Migrations.CreateTokens.change/0 backward
[info] drop index unique_tokens_index
[info] drop index tokens_user_id_index
** (Mariaex.Error) (1553): Cannot drop index 'tokens_user_id_index': needed in a foreign key constraint
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:200: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex:118: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Adapters.MySQL.execute_ddl/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1899: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex:118: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL.execute_ddl/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migration/runner.ex:104: anonymous fn/2 in Ecto.Migration.Runner.flush/0
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1899: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migration/runner.ex:102: Ecto.Migration.Runner.flush/0
    (stdlib) timer.erl:181: :timer.tc/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migration/runner.ex:26: Ecto.Migration.Runner.run/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:128: Ecto.Migrator.attempt/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:106: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Migrator.do_down/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:576: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.do_transaction/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1283: DBConnection.transaction_run/4
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1207: DBConnection.run_begin/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:798: DBConnection.transaction/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:262: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Migrator.migrate/4
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1294: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (ecto) lib/mix/tasks/ecto.rollback.ex:79: anonymous fn/4 in Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Rollback.run/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum.each/2
```

Comment: It seems that you have another table that is referencing the tokens table, using the field `token` of tokens table as a foreign key. If that is correct, then based on this error I would think your regular migration would not even work. Could you do an ecto.reset for it to drop the entire db and re-migrate the whole thing? I expect it will error out.

Answer (score 1):

`ecto.rollback` normally works even if you have indexes and such. By reading the error message it seems that the issue is ecto is trying rolling back a table that has a key used by other table as foreign key. That might be an issue with your migration order perhaps.

For example if you have this migration

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateTokens do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:tokens) do
      add :token, :string
      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all, on_update: :update_all)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:tokens, [:user_id])
    create unique_index(:tokens, [:token], unique: true, name: :unique_tokens_index)
  end
end
```

Your `CreateUsers` migration should have been created first (this means being first with a lower timestamp on the file name) since the CreateTokens depends on `CreateUsers` to establish its foreign_keys.

This error is probably due to you generating the migration and trying to alter it by yourself afterwards. Keep in mind that migrations are time sensitive/order sensitive so you can't create a Token table which references users if you haven't created the User table as well

You could try to run `mix ecto.reset` but since it's getting an error when trying to rollback, it will most likely give you an error when you run the `mix ecto.migrate`

The solution would be fixing the migrations orders or even splitting into more migrations... Such as: CreateUsers, CreateTokens, CreateForeignKeys